# Opening Word file in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am just trying to read the text from Word file, using my web application. It is working fine in my local system, and after I hosted it in the server, the word file is not opening, and its throwing null exception.

This is how I am doing,

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document WordDoc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
object DocNoParam = Type.Missing;
object DocReadOnly = false;
object DocVisible = false;

WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(BO.Misc.Settings.AttachementPathRelative + fileName,
                                            ref DocNoParam,
                                            ref DocReadOnly,
                                            ref DocNoParam,
                                            ref DocNoParam,
                                            ref DocNoParam,
                                            ref DocNoParam,
                                            ref DocNoParam,
                                            ref DocNoParam,
                                            ref DocNoParam,
                                            ref DocVisible,
                                            ref DocNoParam,
                                            ref DocNoParam,
                                            ref DocNoParam,
                                            ref DocNoParam,
                                            ref DocNoParam);

        WordDoc.Activate();
```

I have installed office in the server, and I have given reference of interop to my web application as well. I dunno why I am getting the error. Can anyone help me out here. Thanks in advance.

I am getting error in `WordDoc.Activate()`, the problem is I dont have Visual Studio installed in my system, so am not able to debug it. Its throwing me an exception saying `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

And stack trace is `[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Profile_CreateProfile.btnResumeUpload_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Apps\App1\Employee\AddEmployee.aspx.cs:411
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +153
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3690`

Comment: Post exception details: message, type, stacktrace, line of code throwing exception.

Comment: This is not solving your problem but I think you should use `Path.Combine(...)` instead of `BO.Misc.Settings.AttachementPathRelative + fileName`  `System.IO.Path.Combine(BO.Misc.Settings.AttachementPathRelative, fileName)`. 

`Path.Combine(..)` is more robust.

Comment: @defaultlocale I have updated my question, can you check it now?

Comment: Note that, last I checked, Microsoft Office is not licensed for automation on servers. You should check your license details for clarification.

Comment: I know from experience that using `Office.Interop` on servers can be troublesome. I'd suggest you switch to the OpenXml SDK. The good thing is you'd be working on the Word file directly and won't require Office. The bad thing is you'd need to rewrite a lot of code.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe I think you r right, because am just using trial version only now. Fine I will check it, thanks for ur help.

Comment: did you find solution for this? i've got same error

Answer (score 4):

It's not recommended that you use interop mode in a server environment (e.g ASP application) as "Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment." [(Read this for more details)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757).

You should use [OpenXML](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/317918/Example-For-OpenXML-in-asp-net) to create word documents on a server.

Answer (score -5):

1.verify to the path is correct.
2.verify is this folder were create :
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop
3.if not create

Comment: Is this meant as an answer to *this* 5 year old question?